# Android webView - how to change background color of webView dialog?

Tags: android, html, css, webview, dialog

in android i have a webview that opens fine and i've set it up like this:

```
webView= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview); 
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); 
webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient()); 
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

but now during the webview session there is a listview that pops up and i would like to change the background color of just that
listview. right now its white and i want it to be grey ? is there a way to enforce this ?

The list item is from the web server . im just displaying a webview. i just pass it a url. i dont have an adapter as i do not own the listview. its on a webpage

its my companies web server so i could pass in javascript if that would help. what i am noticing is on some devices the color is different. sometimes grey sometimes white. not sure whats going on. the other thing i noticed from the photo as you can see, the listview is coming outside of the webview Window. That might hint to me that this is a native dialog being used by the webview perhaps. so would there be a theme element i can set in android ?

[image]

Comment: Please add the code of your adapter for the `ListView` and if possible show the minimum code for representing the list item layout.

Comment: the list item is from the web side . im just displaying a webview. i just pass it a url.  i dont have an adapter as i do not own the listview. its on a webpage.

Answer (score 5):

I found out how to do this. The dialog is actually a native dialog even though its invoked from the `WebView`.

So on your `WebView` you should apply a custom `Theme.Dialog` and override the dialog style. Lets show how this can be done:

Create a style like this:

Here's `myStyle.xml`

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="MyDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/orange_transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Then in your `WebView` you can do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    style="@style/myStyle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

Comment: No. `@style/Style` easy. Without postfix ".xml"

Answer (score 0):

You can try apply the style in your activity in manifest file instead of your layout xml file.

Inside your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity
    android:name="com.exmaple.YOUR.ACTIVITY"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/YourCustomStyle">
</activity>
```